# The definite article before names of professions without earlier reference

Tags: articles

Is it correct to use "the" before the name of professions or occupations, even so I mention it for the first time? For example, I explain gymnastics rules for my friends and say:

> To get the highest score **the** gymnast have to perform his routine cleanly.

I don't mean any particular gymnast there. By "the gymnast" I mean that I was talking about all gymnast. So tell me please If my thinking is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you haven't referenced the gymnast before doesn't matter, but this does mean you are talking about one particular gymnast. To mean all gymnasts, you can either use the indefinite article:

> To get the highest score, a gymnast has to perform his or her routine cleanly.

Or, you can just use the plural:

> To get the highest score, gymnasts have to perform their routines cleanly.